# Print negativo, ele só imprime os postivos

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

> Escreva um programa que leia números inteiros da entrada padrão até que seja informado um número negativo. A cada leitura o número lido deve ser escrito na saída padrão.

```
n1 = int(input())
while n1:
  if n1 >= 0:
    print (n1)
    n1 = int(input())
  else:
    print (n1)
break
```

Ele tem que imprimir o numero negativo e não acontece.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Principalmente o `break` está em lugar errado, e sem condição alguma, e se vai sair um esse comando não tem porque complicar, e duplicar a condição. E o código pode ser muito mais simples sem duplicações.

Ele só precisa pedir o dado dentro do laço, verificar se é negativo, e se for deve encerrar, caso contrário continua o fluxo imprimindo e e repetindo. Não tem porque fazer diferente do que o enunciado pede, é uma questão de interpretação de texto.

A pergunta fala que tem que imprimir o negativo, mas o enunciado é ambíguo quanto a isso, geralmente não é o desejado.

Não fiz a verificação se o dado foi digitado errado, se algo que não seja um número for digitado a aplicação quebrará.

```
while True:
    n1 = int(input())
    if n1 < 0:
        break
    print(n1)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jo6iZR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/EndInputpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/EndInput.py).

Se realmente deseja que o negativo deve ser impresso é só uma questão de ordem que as coisas devem ser executadas, então se o `if` estabelece a saída do laço e quer que seja impresso antes de sair, é só colocar o `print()` antes do `if`.

```
while True:
    n1 = int(input())
    print(n1)
    if n1 < 0:
        break
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9g3Wbd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/EndInput2py). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/EndInput2.py).

Comment: Correta interpretação do exercício, porém tentei imprimir um nr negativo usando o print, em python, e não consegui, é alguma limitação do print? Onde posso encontrar mais informações sobre o assunto?

Comment: @LuizAugusto nenhum problema: https://ideone.com/9g3Wbd

Comment: Claro! eu havia colocado dentro do laço `if n1 < 0:` , falha minha, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi do seu enunciado, você precisa criar um programa que `leia` um número `inteiro` e exiba-o. E, no caso em que o número for `negativo`, também o exiba, `porém`, encerre o programa logo em seguida.

Diante deste entendimento, desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
        if n >= 0:
            print(f'\033[32mO valor digitado foi: {n}\033[m')
        else:
            print(f'\033[32mO valor digitado foi: {n}\033[m')
            print('\033[31mEncerrando o programa!')
            for c in range(24):
                sleep(0.1)
                print(f'{chr(46)}', end='')
            print()
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/jsyoajbo-solkarped).

Observe também, que este algoritmo possui um tratamento de erros e exceções, restringindo apenas aceitação de números `inteiros`.